# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect - Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to create Spring REST method with generic parameters.
This method will be calling by Angular http post method.
When i deploy my app i've got error:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

My Java Class with Spring REST method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/store")
public class TestController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class.getName());

@RequestMapping(value = "/order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity handleOrder(@RequestBody Class<?> dataType, 
 @RequestBody Class<?> orderType, @RequestBody Class<?>[] dataArr) {
     LOGGER.debug("TEST" + dataType + " " + orderType + " " + dataArr);
     return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
 }
};
```

My JavaScript file with Angular post method:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    $http.post('/rest/store/order', {
        dataType: "Client",
        orderType: "Simple",
        dataArr: cars }
    );
```

My servlet-mapping in web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Question: How to resolve this error?**

Comment: Why do you expect "Client" and "Simple" to be instances of Class, and ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"] to be an array of Class. They look like Strings to me, not Class. And what you're sending using AngularJS is a single request body (there can't be more than one), as JSON. So your Spring method should expect a single request body, which should be an object with 3 properties dataType, orderType and dataArr, respectively of type String, String and List<String>.